# Replace Specifc Full Links Between href=" " Using PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, html-parsing

I have tried searching through related answers but can't quite find something that is suitable for my specific needs. I have quite a few affiliate links within 1,000s of articles on one of my wordpress sites - which all start with the same url format and sub-domain structure:

```
http://affiliateprogram.affiliates.com/
```

However, after the initial url format, the query string appended changes for each individual url in order to send visitors to specific pages on the destination site.

I am looking for something that will scan a string of html code (the article body) for all href links that include the specific domain above and then replace THE WHOLE LINK (whatever the query string appended) with another standard link of my choice.

```
href="http://affiliateprogram.affiliates.com/?random=query_string&page=destination"
```

gets replaced with

```
href="http://www.mylink.com"
```

**I would ideally like to do this via php** as I have a basic grasp, but if you have any other suggestions I would appreciate all input.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$html = 'href="http://affiliateprogram.affiliates.com/?random=query_string&page=destination"';

echo preg_replace('#http://affiliateprogram.affiliates.com/([^"]+)#is', 'http://www.mylink.com', $html);

?>
```

http://ideone.com/qaEEM

Comment: Wow. Thanks for such a speedy response. This works perfectly and you will of saved me an endless amount of hours doing this manually/or trying to solve it myself. Many thanks

Comment: this is not a complete solution. You must take in account the complete anchor <a ... href ... >

Comment: @webarto As I said your solution does not take in account the complete anchor: so will replace every href="***" in the text, even not real anchors!

Comment: @NomikOS, doesn't matter, point is to replace certain links, not just anchors (altought they are all probably a->href). For more complex cases you it should be done with DOMDocument and not with dozen of (.*?) in regex... this is just a simple replace.

Comment: @webarto It's obvious that he want work over real anchors (is a normal operation of replacing over article's bodies). But please do not evil (.*?) it is a correct pattern and it is applicable in the present scope. OK, was fun, Until the next, peace! o/\o

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression such as:

```
href="(https?:\/\/affiliateprogram.affiliates.com\/[^"]*)"
```

---

```
$data =<<<EOT
  <a href="http://affiliateprogram.affiliates.com/?random=query_string&page=destination">bar</a>
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490284/replace-specifc-full-links-between-href-using-php">foo</a>
  <a name="zz" href="http://affiliateprogram.affiliates.com/?query=random&page=destination&string">baz</a>
EOT;

echo (
  preg_replace (
    '#href="(https?://affiliateprogram.affiliates.com/[^"]*)"#i',
    'href="http://www.mylink.com"',
    $data
  )
);
```

output

```
<a href="http://www.mylink.com">bar</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490284/replace-specifc-full-links-between-href-using-php">foo</a>
<a name="zz" href="http://www.mylink.com">baz</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = '<a class="***" href="http://affiliateprogram.affiliates.com/?random=query_string&page=destination" attr="***">';

$b = preg_replace("/<a([^>]*)href=\"http:\/\/affiliateprogram\.affiliates\.com\/[^\"]*\"([^>]*)>/", "<a\\1href=\"http://www.mylink.com/\"\\2>", $a);

var_dump($b); // <a class="***" href="http://www.mylink.com/" attr="***">
```

Comment: While looking for the complete tag might be the better approach, the `<a(.*?)href` is too simplistic. It will fail for any `<a name=` tags and then span over multiple tags. It might still work, but isn't quite the more precise pattern you were aiming for.

Comment: @mario I have worked a lot with regexp. Yes you right. You must know that `if you apply regular expression to solve one problem you will have 2 problems` :) in nay case this sopution will work in the scope presented by Ben.

Comment: Yeah, but so will the simpler ones. And looking for the anchor but ignoring the filler is not a structural and resiliency benefit.

Comment: @mario what do you mean? this will work over any <aXXXhref="...affiliat..."XXX> I don't only use (.*?) that besides is a very useful pattern when used right. In this case will catch all legat HTML between `<a` and `href=`.

Comment: Given the input `<a name=xy><a href=...>` your regex will match over two tags at once. Thus making your bickering about non-complete patterns a bit redundant.

Comment: @mario good sample, you right, editing now. but consider that I originally used ([^>]*) in the second backreference. Besides we could consider "|' and other things. OK, THX for the heads up!

Answer (score -1):

That's quite simple, as you only need a single placeholder for the querystring. `.*?` would normally do, but you can make it more specific by matching anything that's not a double quote:

```
$html =
preg_replace('~ href="http://affiliateprogram\.affiliates\.com/[^"]*"~i',
              ' href="http://www.mylink.com"', $html);
```

People will probably come around and recomend a longwinded [domdocument](/questions/tagged/domdocument) approach, but that's likely overkill for such a task.

Comment: +1 for DOMDocument being long-winded for what is really just a text replacement.

Comment: Not insinuating it's completely useless. But this task is most certainly well-known output transformation, not a arbitrary web garbage HTML input. So just looking for the desired target probably ok.

Comment: this is not a complete solution. You must take in account the complete anchor <a ... href ... >

Comment: Thank you for your help. Both the suggestions I have commented on work perfectly and are easy to implement with my basic php knowledge.

Comment: @webarto no my friend. you should take in account an effective solution. is very easy work just with href.